# Is it possible to add an hour to the timestamp in log4net using the ConversionPattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net, log4net-configuration

We have a situation where the server is in Germany and we're based in the UK. We want the log4net logs to show a timestamp that is GMT, but I can't work out how or if it's possible to add an hour to the time being written to the log file.

This is our current config:

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="logs\\" />
  <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.fff} %-5level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I found some references online to an "hourOffset", but this doesn't seem to work and never appears in the log4net documentation.

Any advise here would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `utcdate` instead of `d` (or `date`). See also the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html).

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%utcdate{yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.fff} %-5level - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks.I did try utcdate, but the problem with that was that it would be out by 1 hour for half the year depending on daylight savings.

Comment: @JacksonW6 - You asked for adding the GMT date and time as the value of the time stamp. [GMT = UTC](https://www.google.com/search?q=gmt+vs+utc). [GMT/UTC does not observe daylight savings time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I meant the local UK time, which should always be 1 hour ahead of the server time.

Comment: @JacksonW6 - there is nothing built into log4net to convert the time stamp to a different locale. Why would you want to do this in the log file though? Personally I would also prefer a UTC value as it is unambiguous.

Comment: The reason is that the only people accessing the log files would be the dev team in our UK office, often in response to a support issue logged at a particular time. As in, an email saying something didn't work that we receive at 10:30am. We check the log file for the corresponding time to see if any exceptions are appearing at that time. With a one hour difference, we'd need to be adding an hour each time -- easy to miss if someone isn't that familiar with the log files.

Comment: @JacksonW6 - you will have to create your own implementation of `log4net.Layout.PatternLayout`.